# Text after \end{addmargin} does not indent

Tags: indentation

the text following \indent does not indent after \end{addmargin}. Am I missing something?

```
\begin{addmargin}[1cm]{1cm}
Text
\end{addmargin}
\indent Text
```

Comment: You need to give a test file that shows the behaviour that people can debug, `addmargin` isn't  even a standard command and you give no hint of its definition, but even with that the indentation after an environment typically depends on global settings in the document and the text before the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KOMA-Script provides environment `addmargin`. So maybe you use either a KOMA-Script class or a different class in combination with package `scrextend`.

You have to leave the vertical mode before `\indent`:

```latex
\begin{addmargin}[1cm]{1cm}
Text
\end{addmargin}
\leavevmode\indent Text
```

But if »Text« should be begin a new paragraph then you can simple use `\par` after `\end{addmargin}`

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\begin{document}
\begin{addmargin}{1cm}
Text
\end{addmargin}
\par% <- starts a new paragraph
Text
\end{document}
```

or use an empty line in the source code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\begin{document}
\begin{addmargin}{1cm}
Text
\end{addmargin}

Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \leavevmode worked fine ! thanks!